# Ray voxel intersection

Tags: c#, math, voxel

I want to test for an intersection of a ray with a voxel field.

I could naively crawl through the voxel field by calculating a ray-box intersection with the edge of the current voxel, then doing the same for the next voxel until I hit something. But isn't there a faster way to trace through a voxel field? I was thinking something along the lines of [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) in 3D, something that could quickly give me all of the cells a given line intersects. Anyone done this before?

Due to certian limitations and the fact that these ray traces aren't happening that often, I do not want to build an octree or any other data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21057-3d-bresenhams-line-generation) an implementation of Bresenham's in 3D. It's in matlab; if you don't speak that you can see a [C implementation here](ftp://ftp.isc.org/pub/usenet/comp.sources.unix/volume26/line3d).

Answer (score -2):

I believe the octree-algorithm does what your asking for.

Comment: Octree is a data structure, not an algorithm.